# Http vs Https for MP3s on Playlist

Tags: deezer

When looking at the URL for MP3's of tracks on a playlist, there seems to be a discrepancy between http/https.

If you use this URL, it shows the preview MP3 using http:
[HTTP](https://api.deezer.com/playlist/935381445/tracks?output=xml)

`http://e-cdn-preview-0.deezer.com/stream/0bccd6ed095e39534e14107199dadaa8-3.mp3`

If you use this URL, it shows the preview MP3 using https: [HTTPS](https://api.deezer.com/playlist/935381445&output=xml)

```
https://e-cdns-preview-0.dzcdn.net/stream/0bccd6ed095e39534e14107199dadaa8-3.mp3
```

This is for the first track on the playlist with the title "Me Rehúso"

The only difference in the API calls is the addition of "/tracks?" to pull only the tracks. The one that returns HTTPS is a simple Playlist call. The one that returns HTTP is pulling only the tracks from a playlist.

Which version of this is correct?

Comment: Thank you for this report, we will fix that. The main idea that we have is that if you are requesting our API in HTTPS, you will retrieve links in HTTPS. If you are requesting our API in HTTP, you will retrieve links in HTTP.

Comment: We released a fix, thank you for your patience!